# VB Getting The SubFolder name and saving it to a Text file

Tags: vb.net, subdirectory

I want to get The Subfolder Name Listed in my Textfile. 
I don't want to see the path for the SubFolder.
I finally got a way to show only to my VS Console. But If i try to save it to my txt file it keeps on writing only the first line even though I used For. Please Help Me!
Here's the code that writes to the console

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(startPath)
        Dim Drs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()
        For Each dr As IO.DirectoryInfo In Drs
            Console.WriteLine(dr.Name)
        Next
```

This is the code that I tried to Write It on a txt file. It only writes 1 Line

```
For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(startPath)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Test.txt", Dir, False)
        Next
```

The Expected Output is

```
SubFolder1
SubFolder2
SubFolder3
SubFolder4
SubFolder5
```

Like this in txt file

Comment: Show the code that writes to the file since that is the code you want to get fixed by us

Comment: @wingedpanther I added the expected output on the question

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added the code that writes to the txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method, `WriteAllText` always overwrites the complete file, you want  to append a new line. You could use [`File.AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(startPath)
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\Test.txt", Dir)
Next
```

Another option, use a `StreamWriter`, it has a [constructor that takes a `Boolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) to append text:

```
Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(startPath, True)
    For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(startPath)
        writer.WriteLine(Dir)
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the problem well! I didn't know there were more Methods. I'll Try to look deeper in the msdn

Comment: @노재형: yes, especially look at the `System.IO` namespace and the `File` or `Directory` classes that contain a lot of useful methods. Of course you could also use a `StreamWriter`(it has a [constructor that takes a `Boolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) to append text). But normally the `File` methods are more comfortable. You don't need to use `Using` to ensure that it gets disposed properly.  Edited my answer to include it.